# Looking for unused symbols in Lua

Tags: lua, symbols

I'm trying to embed Lua in my host program but my host program doesn't allow users to type '\', '{' and '}' symbols.

I need to use '{' and '}' for table construction so I'm looking for alternative symbols that are unused in Lua so I can replace these symbols internally before sending the code to an interpreter.

I'm a beginner in Lua and would like know if there's any symbol which is never used in Lua programming language. (except when used in a string)

I personally am guessing the grave accent symbol (`) is not used in Lua.
I would appreciate if anyone can confirm this.

Thanks!

Comment: `!@$?` are not used by Lua

Comment: Combinations `</` and `/>` are never occured in Lua syntax

Comment: If you cannot use `{...}` for table construction, you could use `table.pack(...)` instead (>= Lua 5.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically the grave accent doesn't seem to be used and you can check it yourself by looking at the [complete syntax of Lua section in the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#9).

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not currently used in `Lua`, so you are fine. It might also be useful to know that `Lua`, as most of programming languages, has some special (magic) characters that when used in a specific context convey a special meaning. Take a look at the [official documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html).